# Mains filtering for 1050 Hz signals

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, mains

What type of passive filter could be made to remove 1050 Hz digital signals from my SMPS?

Comment: Lowpass or notch come to mind, but why are there digital signals on your SMPS?  What's the amplitude of the signals (presumably) on the output, and how much attenuation do you need?  The frequency is too low to put the filter inside the control loop, so how much added impedance can you put up with?  Have you tried other methods to decouple the noise?

Comment: @anthony please include what kind of smps you have or some specs

Comment: 1050 Hz is a very low frequency for an SMPS. Are you certain it is correct ?

Comment: 6-7 Volts of Digital Transmissions by the Authorities, in Pulses of up to 30 seconds, Affecting many LED drivers

Comment: How much do they need to be attenuated by the filter?

Answer (score 1):

For reference about mains signals injected ...

https://goughlui.com/2014/02/02/project-analyze-mains-power-flicker-issue-ripple-signalling/

Here is an example of removing 1050 Hz, 10 V peak ... with coupled inductors (soft coupling K=0.5).

**Without filter**

[image]

**With filter, AC analysis** ...

[image]

**And transient analysis results**

[image]

**Another topology** that seems more efficient (coupling is ~= 1, inductor lower)

**Inductors** ... Something as these (coupling ~ 1). [Inductors](https://docs.rs-online.com/cc2d/0900766b8157af9d.pdf) must pass 10 A rms at 50 Hz.

**AC Analysis**. NB : If coupling=1, the rejection would be almost -60 dB. The charge doesn't matter too much. **Resonance do not shift.** The greater the load (Current higher), the better the rejection filter behaves.

[image]

**TRAN Analysis**

[image]

Comment: Awesome , I will work on the above principle, thanks

Comment: Thanks Everyone for this advice , i am still following up on it

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the first step would be to determine if this is even a problem. Maybe the 1080 Hz signal will not cause any problems for you.

But if it does, one simple idea is to put a 100 uF or 470 uF capacitor on the output of your SMPS, if possible (if it will remain stable with this much capacitance). At 1080 Hz, the 100 uF capacitor is a load of 1.4 Ohms or so. And a 470 uF capacitor is 0.3 Ohms. This low impedance load will attenuate the 1080 Hz signal by a substantial, but not necessarily well-defined amount.

It is not well-defined, because the impedance of the signal source is not well-defined.